# Images Distorting in Safari

Tags: css, safari

When I hover over the images on the below page in Safari they will distort for a split second:
http://bit.ly/1zEqV3Q

It only seems to happen after the small thumbnails slide down.  Does anyone know why this is happening in Safari?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding `-webkit-transform: translateZ(0); transform: translateZ(0);` to your product image style. For me that little line solves all my rendering issues related to transformation in Safari.